# Need guidance in Github merge

Tags: github, merge, gitbox

I am new to managing code revisions and need guidance on how to merge to code sets.  I have a MASTER branch with my latest UI and I have a branch called "Feature-A" with lots of Django additions + template additions to the previous UI files.

Since I am new to Github, I want to take the safest approach incase I need to revert mistakes.  Should I make a new brach of master and merge Feature-A into that branch or should I merge Feature-A directly into the MASTER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're new, I would say the best approach would be to create another branch (clone of master branch) and then merge feature A into that, and see if it works. If not, keep testing feature A to make it compatible. If it works, great! Just remove that extra branch and merge feature A into the master.

I.e., 
`git checkout master`
Then, create a new branch (`git checkout -b 'featuretest'`)
Now, `git branch` shows 
`* master` 
`* featureA` 
`* featuretest`

Then, do `git checkout featuretest`, and `git merge featureA` to merge it.

If the feature works, great! Remove the branch (`git checkout master; git branch -d featuretest`)
and do it for real (`git merge featureA`)

If the feature doesn't work, go back to the feature branch (`git checkout feature`) and keep testing.